# How to get my VM to run faster?

Tags: eclipse, virtual-machine, virtualbox

So I am running a VirtualBox VM for a Big Data Programming class I am currently in. I'm not entirely sure what kind of specifications to mention to provide any insight, but I have around 95GB of memory left on my Macbook Pro. I have to code in Eclipse Luna in the VM, but once the VM is up and running, opening up Eclipse takes an obscene amount of time. Is this a memory issue, and would buying an external hard drive be the best course of action? When I brought this issue to my professor that seemed to be his consensus(its a memory issue), but I wanted to get a wider array of opinions/help.

Comment: You are confusing memory (ram) with memory (hard disk space). I would guess you don't have enough RAM, so adding a new HDD won't help. Running low on disk space does not degrade performance

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you have a RAM bottleneck. Try increase the amount of RAM allocated to the virtual machine. In VirtualBox:

1. Power off your virtual machine in Virtual Box
2. Select the virtual machine you are using
3. Click on Settings
4. Click on System
5. Increase the amount of RAM "Base Memory" dedicated to the virtual machine
6. Click Ok.

Note: Be sure to not add so much that you make the host go slower. Try testing with different amounts until it is optimal performance.

Here is a possibly related resource to help you resolve your problem:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=39368

Comment: I have the RAM "Base Memory" almost to the max amount allowed. Any other tips?

Comment: There have been reports of issues with VirtualBox actually slowing down with the more processor cores set in settings. How many processors have you set your VM to use?

Comment: I have it set to use two processors, the max allowed for my machine. The same issue seemed to be happening when I had it set to just one.

Comment: Okay the last option I can think of is to Disable the Vtx and nested paging under Settings -> Hardware Acceleration. If that doesn't help it could just be down to your systems lack of resources.